# MDX, SSAS 2005 calculating SPLY (Same Period Last Year)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to achieve the following: I have a measure: *[Measures].[Sales]* and a time dimmension: *[Time].[Year - Month - Day].* I would like to add new measure: *[Measures].[Sales SPLY]* to work in the following way:

MONTH-----------------Sales--------------Sales SPLY

2009 January--------120 000,00--------110 000,00

2009 February ------100 000,00--------90 000,00

2009 March----------120 000,00--------110 000,00

TOTAL:---------------340 000,00--------**290 000,00**

The value of [Sales SPLY] is calculates using the following way: I created a new Sum measure, and in a Cube Script I replace it with the following code:

```
([Measures].[Sales SPLY], Leaves([Time])) = (PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Year - Month - Day].[Year],1,[Time].[Year - Month - Day].currentmember), [MEASURES].[Sales])
```

It's working, however is just very, very slow. Does anyone know a better way of writing this MDX? using only the parrarel period in a calculated member will result in a bad value of the Total in SPLY measure. Please, I googled a lot and couldn't find any thing better than this.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to just create a member like

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Sales SPLY] as ([Measures].[Sales], ParallelPeriod([Time].[Year - Month - Day].[Year],1,[Time].[Year - Month - Day].currentmember))
SELECT {[Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Sales SPLY]} ON 0, ....
```

And it works fine.

How are you using it in your query overall?

Rob

Comment: I need to add this as a member to a cube. The query you provided will return good results. However when users browse the cube, expand the time dimension and select only part of the year the total for the SPLY is wrong (it's a sum of the whole previous year). The issue is mentioned here: http://books.google.com/books?id=-4lFAurTLl0C&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=mdx+ssas+same+period+last+year&source=bl&ots=8G-mKLrMBy&sig=4o4H-NVk51DCsmKMhrBnrL48F84#v=onepage&q=&f=false 
However I could find the solution...

Comment: Will a LastYearToDate member, that uses a combination of ParallelPeriod and YTD help?

Comment: Sorry Adam - I have to run... I'll check back later.

Comment: Unfortunatelly users can select periods containg two months: 2008 December and 2009 January, and the Sales SPLY should show the sum of sales in 2007 December and 2008 January.

Comment: Yup, shouldn't be a problem. Let me check on one of own cubes to see if the behaviour is what I think it is.